# Making network call to receive image and show it when location access has been granted

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-location

i'm wanting to make a network call when location access has been granted. so i'm using `LaunchedEffect(key1 = location.value){...}` to decide when to make that network call to recompose, but facing some issues.

upon initial launch user is greeted with the location request (either precise or coarse). during this, the  `Toast.makeText(context, "Allow location access in order to see image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` get's called twice and shows up twice. when the user selects an option from the location request dialog, i would assume `location.value` would end up changing and `viewModel.getImage(location.value!!)` get's called. debugging through this, that all happens, but the image doesn't end up showing. i got it to work sometimes by force closing the app, then opening it again, then the image shows up. any insights? here is the location code in that same file:

```
    val locationLiveData = LocationLiveData(context)
    val location = locationLiveData.observeAsState()

    val requestSinglePermissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
        when {
            it.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                locationLiveData.startLocationUpdates()
            }
            it.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                locationLiveData.startLocationUpdates()
            } else -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Allow location access", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        }
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationLiveData.startLocationUpdates()
    } else {
        // true so we execute once not again when we compose or so
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
            requestSinglePermissionLauncher.launch(arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**
LocationLiveData

```
class LocationLiveData(var context: Context): LiveData<LocationDetails>() {
    // used to get last known location
    private val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

    // We have at least 1 observer or 1 component looking at us
    // here we can get the last known location of the device
    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
            setLocationData(it)
        }
    }

    // no one is looking at this live data anymore
    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    }

    internal fun startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
    }

    private fun setLocationData(location: Location) {
        value = LocationDetails(longitude = location.longitude.toString(), latitude = location.latitude.toString())
    }

    private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(p0)
            for (location in p0.locations) {
                setLocationData(location)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val ONE_MINUTE: Long = 60_000
        val locationRequest: LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = ONE_MINUTE
            fastestInterval = ONE_MINUTE / 4
            priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
    }
}
```

**COMPOSABLE**

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(), navigateToAuthScreen: () -> Unit, navigateToAddImage: () -> Unit){
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val locationLiveData = remember { LocationLiveData(context) }
    val location = locationLiveData.observeAsState()

    val requestSinglePermissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
        when {
            it.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                locationLiveData.startLocationUpdates()
            }
            it.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                locationLiveData.startLocationUpdates()
            }
        }
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationLiveData.startLocationUpdates()
    } else {
        // true so we execute once not again when we compose or so
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
            requestSinglePermissionLauncher.launch(arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
        }
    }

    Scaffold( topBar = {
        HomeScreenTopBar()
    },
        floatingActionButton = {
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
            if (location.value != null) {
                navigateToAddImageScreen()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "allow location access to add image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        },
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = "Save note"
            )
        }
    }) {innerPadding ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(innerPadding)) {
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = location.value) {
                if (location.value != null) {
                    viewModel.getListings(location.value!!)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Allow location access in order to see image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
val locationLiveData = LocationLiveData(context)
```

creates a new `LocationLiveData` instance on every recomposition.

You have to remember the same instance of `LocationLiveData` across recompositions, if you want it to hold any state or view state.

Change it to

```
// remember LocationLiveData across recompositions
// this does not survive configuration changes, nor other short Activity restarts
val locationLiveData = remember { LocationLiveData(context) }
```

As also mentioned in the code comment above, now `locationLiveData` will survive re-compositions, but it will still get reset on:

1. every configuration change (examples include but are not limited to:
   orientation change, light/dark mode change, language change...)
2. every short Activity restart, caused by the system in some cases
3. also application death (but that is somewhat expected)

To solve 1. and 2. you can use [`rememberSaveable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/package-summary#rememberSaveable(kotlin.Array,androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.Saver,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0)) that can save primitive and other [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize) types automatically (in your case you can also implement the [`Saver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/Saver) interface), to solve 3. you have to save the state to any of the persistent storage options and then restore as needed.

To learn more about working with state in Compose see the documentation section on [Managing State](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state). This is fundamental information to be able to work with state in Compose and trigger recompositions efficiently. It also covers the fundamentals of [state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting). If you prefer a coding tutorial here is the [code lab for State in Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#0).

An introduction to handling the state as the complexity increases is in the video from Google about [Using Jetpack Compose's automatic state observation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmv2ug-wW4U).

Comment: thx for the info. i've changed it to be this:
`val locationLiveData = remember { LocationLiveData(context) }` but the same issues persist. the toast notifications show up twice and the data doesn't get loaded on the screen. but leaving the app, then opening it up again, the data shows up

Comment: and by toast notifications, i mean the one in the question above: 
#1: `Allow location access in order to see image` and also this one that i added above: 
#2: `Allow location access to add image`

now, when the screen loads up, #1 shows up, then #2, then #1 again. i assume none would show up except #1 (because #2 should show up when the user taps the floating action button) and it would only show up once

Comment: i wonder if the key i'm using `location.value` in the launched effect is the reason for these issues? i tried using just `location` but that didn't work either

Comment: It is not clear how the whole code fits together because you posted it in 3 separate parts without the enclosing function name. Post you composable also as a single whole part. Depends on what your `locationLiveData.value` is in the beginning and how calling `locationLiveData.startLocationUpdates()` changes it, or what else changes it.

Comment: @raazza Please also post the code for `LocationLiveData`.

Comment: sure, let me do that

Comment: just posted them. regarding my 2nd comment related to 2 different toasts showing up, it's actually just #1 that shows up twice, fixed the issue with #2 showing up

Comment: any insight @Ma3x?

Comment: @raazza I have run the code that you added to your answer on an Android 9 phone and on an Android 11 tablet and in both cases the bottom toast is called only once every time I navigate to the screen. If no permission is granted, it shows the toast once and shows the permission prompt right away, if I grant it, it gets the location once per minute, if permission is already granted it shows the toast once and then it gets the location once per minute. If in your case you see the toast twice, you will have to debug, because maybe your whole HomeScreen is leaving the composition and reentering it.

Comment: @razza The only way that `LaunchedEffect(key1 = location.value)` can get called twice with a `null` value is if the value goes `null` -> non `null` -> `null` _or_  if somehow the screen leaves and enters the composition again. So it is either some code that is missing in your question _or_ it might be version/OS/device specific behavior. But I think you cant even set the value to `null` again yourself, since the `LiveData` is defined as containing a non-nullable type, so you will have to debug this on your device and see what is going on. Are you seeing this behavior on a device or simulator?

Comment: @razza Add this to the top of your `HomeScreen` composable `LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) { Log.d("Test", "HomeScreen entered composition") }` navigate to your `HomeScreen` _once_, allow the permission when asked, then check the log, and report back how many times do you see this message in the log.

Comment: just debugged it, when it hits the home screen, that log statement is called. then it goes inside `LaunchedEffect(key1 = location.value) {`, and since `location.value` is null, it shows the toast. right after showing the toast, it then goes back up again to that log statement. and then it jumps back down to the launched effect and since `location.value` is still null, it shows the toast again

Comment: Ah!! figured it out! the navigation function that navigates to the home screen was getting called twice, so i wrapped it in a `LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){...}` and now it works! thx so much for ur help

Comment: @raazza Very nice! So it was a case of leaving and re-entering the composition due to the navigation happening twice. But you got it now.